# OSX Cocoa - How to test for changes in multiple NSTextFields

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, osx-mountain-lion, nstextfield

I am trying to test for changes in some NSTextFields.

I'm using:

```
- (void)controlTextDidEndEditing:(NSNotification *)notification {

    if ([notification object] == field1) 
        NSLog(@"field1: stringValue == %@", [field1 stringValue]);

    if ([notification object] == field2) 
        NSLog(@"field2: stringValue == %@", [field2 stringValue]);

    if ([notification object] == field3)
        NSLog(@"field3: stringValue == %@", [field3 stringValue]);

}
```

This works, but I wonder if there is a better way. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite OK.

`field1` etc I am expecting to be outlets.

You can do just a step better :

```
- (void)controlTextDidEndEditing:(NSNotification *)notification {

    if ([notification object] == field1) 
        NSLog(@"field1: stringValue == %@", [field1 stringValue]);

    else if ([notification object] == field2) 
        NSLog(@"field2: stringValue == %@", [field2 stringValue]);

    else if ([notification object] == field3)
        NSLog(@"field3: stringValue == %@", [field3 stringValue]);

}
```

Comment: @DavidDelMonte: One suggestion "Never accept the answer within 24 hours unless you got more than one answers, and one answer has significant upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Key-Value-Observing](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html) ( KVO)  to catch any value changes.

```
[field1 addObserver:self
         forKeyPath:@"text"
             options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew |
                        NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld)
                context:NULL];
```

You will have to implement method in observer:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                  ofObject:(id)object
                    change:(NSDictionary *)change
                   context:(void *)context {

if ([keyPath isEqual:@"text"]) {
      if ( [object isMemberOfClass: [//class of object you have passed //]]){
         //project class you are processing and then use  a log
         NSLog(@"object: stringValue == %@", [field2 stringValue]);
      }

}
/*
 Be sure to call the superclass's implementation *if it implements it*.
 NSObject does not implement the method.
 */
[super observeValueForKeyPath:keyPath
                     ofObject:object
                       change:change
                       context:context];
```

}

Comment: Thank you too. Are there any performance issues either way? (I have about 10 fields)

Comment: KVO is part of Cocoa framework - guess this should be fast enough for most solutions.